# Cardano-node updated to 1.33.0 - gLiveView not connecting to node

Tags: cardano-node

I have updated my relay node to 1.33.0 and gLiveView will not run.  The node is up and running and I can see it working with simpleLiveView, but when i run gLiveView I get an error. "could not connect to running instance"

Node is running
[image: Node is running]

simpleLiveView
[image: simpleLiveView]

Node version is 1.33.0
[image]

This is the error for gLiveView
[image]

Any ideas where I can start to troubleshoot the issue?
Thanks,

Comment: Have you ensured that all your path variables are set appropriately in your `~/.bashrc` folder, and that gLiveView is updated to the latest version (v1.25.1)?

Answer (score 0):

if i am right, that you use cntools, please read below...

take a backup of your files in the folder "scripts",

and download again the env and gLive files.

if you want download all your files, just to be updated.

```
cd tmp/
./prereqs.sh -f
```

but please, dont forget to take backup of your current files, so that you bring back the settings to env file and the rest you use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes that is correct I use cntools. In my env file the only change I have made is to set the port `CNODE_PORT=6000` like in the guild-operators common env  [link] (https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/Scripts/env/) is there something else i shoud check in the env file?  Should I replace all the script files in the folder or just the gLive files?

Comment: it looks you run a relay, then is fine only the setting for the port. - when you ask me for all files or only gLive, i used to update all files once per month. it is good. but you dont have to. - it would be nice if you vote my answers if that helps you mate.

Comment: Yeah, it did not solve my issue.  I did the ./prereqs.sh update, but still cannot run gLiveView